# Java RMI from external IP

Tags: java, server, ip, rmi

I used java RMI to connect two java applications. if i run them both locally *(and change ip to localhost)* it works, if i run them both on my server it works. but if i run Client.java locally and ApplicationServer.java on my server it throws this on the client side:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: my.servers.private.ip; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect ...
```

Client:

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException NotBoundException {
                System.out.println("attempting connection");

                System.setProperty("java.security.policy","test.policy");
                HelloService service =(HelloService) Naming.lookup("rmi://my.servers.private.ip:1001/hello");

                System.out.println("connected");
                if(service.isConnected()) {
                       System.out.println("success.");
                }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public class ApplicationServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, AlreadyBoundException {
                System.setProperty("java.security.policy","test.policy");
                System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","my.servers.private.ip");

                Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1001);
                registry.rebind("hello", new HelloServant());
                System.out.println("ready");
    }
}
```

If i change the code from `my.servers.private.ip` to `my.servers.public.ip` and run both on my server it doesn't work either.
Changing `my.servers.private.ip` to `my.servers.public.ip` does not work.

I have a feeling it has to do something with the public and private IP.

Comment: Are you getting this on the lookup or when calling one of your remote methods?

Comment: And can you ping your public IP address from your private IP address? And from the client host?

Comment: @user207421 I'm getting this on lookup! i can't even get connected. and I cannot ping my.servers.public.ip from the server. i can ping my.servers.private.ip from server. I cant ping from client either.

Comment: This is all due to network connectivity issues, not RMI or even Java. You need to sort out your network.

Comment: @user207421 do you have any idea or tips where i should start? i really dont know much about networking